# Simple TRIGGER which deletes a specific record based on a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a TRIGGER in MySql.

```
notifications_posts
notification_id from_user   on_post_id  in_group_id date
2   1   162 3   2012-07-11 12:01:08
3   19  163 1   2012-07-11 12:03:26
4   19  164 1   2012-08-10 17:42:36
5   1   165 3   2012-08-29 12:14:01
6   1   165 3   2012-08-29 12:14:29
11  1   2   3   2012-08-29 14:38:42
```

Sometimes I need to delete posts, for example with this command:

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE posts.post_id = 165;
```

After this, I want a TRIGGER that deletes all records from `notification_id` according to that id.

This is what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CleanNotificationPosts
AFTER DELETE ON posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM notifications_posts WHERE notifications_posts.id = THAT_ID_TO_DELETE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is my syntax correct?  Do I really need delimiters?

Comment: is there a question or is a revision code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > do I really need delimiters?

   With the syntax as you currently have it: yes, you do need to use a delimiter other than the default `;`—otherwise the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement will be terminated by the `;` before the `END` keyword, which will result in a parse error (as the `BEGIN ... END` block will not have been terminated).

   However, since there is only one statement inside that block, you don't actually need to use `BEGIN ... END` at all:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CleanNotificationPosts
   AFTER DELETE ON posts
   FOR EACH ROW
   DELETE FROM notifications_posts WHERE notifications_posts.id = THAT_ID_TO_DELETE;
   ```

   In this case, no change of statement delimiter is required: the `;` is indeed where the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement is terminated.
2. > Is my syntax correct?

   Almost, but not quite.  Instead of `THAT_ID_TO_DELETE`, you should use `OLD.post_id`.  As stated in [`CREATE TRIGGER` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-trigger.html):

   > You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases `OLD` and `NEW`. `OLD.col_name` refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. `NEW.col_name` refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

   Also, `OR REPLACE` is not valid in MySQL.  You can instead `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` before executing your `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

   Therefore:

   ```
   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS CleanNotificationPosts;
   CREATE TRIGGER CleanNotificationPosts
   AFTER DELETE ON posts
   FOR EACH ROW
   DELETE FROM notifications_posts WHERE notifications_posts.id = OLD.post_id;
   ```
3. However, in this situation you don't actually need to use a trigger at all (as a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) with `ON DELETE CASCADE` will suffice):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE notifications_posts
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES posts (post_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
   ```

   Note the following pre-requisites in order to add such a foreign key constraint:

   - both tables must use the InnoDB storage engine;
   - there must be an index in the `posts` table of which `post_id` is the first column; and
   - there must be a matching record in `posts.post_id` for all non-`NULL` `notifications_posts.id` (down to the column type, including its size & sign).

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, but are you sure that i have to use `OLD`? `You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.`

Comment: i mean the action happens after a delete on a post

Comment: or the "OLD" refers to "that id that was upon a time in the past .." ?

Comment: `OLD` refers to the values that were in the record on which the trigger is acting immediately prior to the `DELETE` statement being executed.  Therefore, in the example in your question `OLD.post_id` will be `165`.

Comment: thank you, i understand, but can you explain me please why my syntax is wrong? http://codepad.org/hKTVWIAw ?? thank you

Comment: @Empeus: The code isn't C, it's SQL!  How have you managed to create and populate the underlying table?  Where are you entering the `DELETE ...` statement?  It goes there.

Comment: first of all, i use codepad just to have text uploaded somewhere, second, i have a syntax error, and i don't know how to solve it, basically i want to have your example but with DELIMITER, understand?

Comment: @Empeus: Why do you want to use `DELIMITER` with my example, when I said "*In this case, no change of statement delimiter is required*"?  In any event, the syntax error (would have been helpful if you included it somewhere: I was just going by the output shown beneath your codepad paste) is probably because you're missing an `=` in your `WHERE` clause.  Just copy & paste the code example I gave under `2.` above.

Comment: it was the `=` ... how could i do this mistake?!? ... anyway, thank you for your kindness, i know i don't have to use `DELIMITER` but i have to learn more and more every day. Thank you!